# Regex only grab part of string - numbers only with a max length

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help with a C# regex expression. Basically I'm rewriting an airport METAR to a friendlier format.

For those who are not familiar with a METAR, here's an example: **KLAX 020353Z 24004KT 9SM FEW150 SCT250 21/18 A2987 RMK AO2 SLP112 T02060178 $**

Basically what I want to do is rewrite the FEW150 to read "few clouds at 150". I'm not great at regex expressions, and here's what I have (which obviously doesn't work):

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, "^FEW[0-9]{3}$", "few clouds at $1");
```

Can anyone help me find the right pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, "FEW([0-9]{3})", "few clouds at $1");
```

`^` marks the beginning of string and `$` marks the end of string and so it wasn't able to match it because your target string is in middile and not the only the string

`$1` refers to the first capture group but there wasn't any in your case..

---

You could also do it this way

```
modify.Substring(modify.IndexOf("FEW"),modify.IndexOf("FEW")+5);
```

Comment: Yes. The `^` and `$` denote 'beginning' and 'end' of string. And the `FEW...` part is in the middle.

Comment: Beautiful! I'll accept this answer in 5 minutes when it'll let me. :)